# Error when using update query

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm using Angular along with SLIM to develop a REST API with information about teams and players.  My POST, GET and DELETE's are working fine but i'm getting an error when I try to post to the players table. The error message is:

Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match

I have looked at all my bound variables and I can't see where the problem is.  I've shown some of the relevant code below so hopefully someone can help me.

HTML

```
<div ng-show="editorEnabled">
                                <p>Name
                                    <input ng-model="player.player_name">
                                </p>
                                <p>DOB
                                    <input ng-model="player.player_dob">
                                </p>
                                <p>Nationality
                                    <input ng-model="player.player_nationality">
                                </p>
                                <p>Position
                                    <input ng-model="player.player_position">
                                </p>
                                <p>Club
                                    <input ng-model="player.club_name">
                                </p>
                                <a href="#" ng-click="editorEnabled=!editorEnabled; updatePlayer(player)">Save <span class="fa fa-save"></span></a>
                            </div>
```

JS/Angular Controller

```
$scope.updatePlayer = function (player) {

    $scope.player = player;
    var id = $scope.player.id;
    console.log($scope.player);

    $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'players.php/players/' + id,
        data: $scope.player,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });

};
```

At this point the console shows that information has been sent over correctly and as expected.

PHP

```
     function updatePlayer($id){
  $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $body = $request->getBody();
    $player= json_decode($body);
    $sql = "Update players SET player_name=:player_name, player_position=:player_position, player_nationality=:player_nationality, player_dob=:player_dob WHERE id=:id";
try{
    $db = getConnection();
     $stmt =$db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("player_name", $player->player_name);
    $stmt->bindParam("player_position", $player->player_position);
    $stmt->bindParam("player_nationality", $player->player_nationality);
    $stmt->bindParam("player_dob", $player->player_dob);
    $stmt->bindParam("club_name", $player->club_name);
    $stmt->bindParam("id", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $db = null;
    responseJson(json_encode($player),200);    
}catch(PDOException $e){
    responseJson('{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}}', 500);

}   
}
```

Comment: You are binding the `club_name` without ever using it in the update query. Thats what the error message tries to tell you quite cryptically.

Comment: You should focus on increasing your readability so you can debug a lot easier....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message suggests, the number of variables bound to the statement does not match the number of variables actually used in the update query:

The `club_name` parameter is never used in the `UPDATE` query. Just remove the

`$stmt->bindParam("club_name", $player->club_name);`

or add the `club_name` to the query and you should be fine.